# apache vhost setup doesnt work

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

First things first .. im pretty new to apache configuration.

I'm trying to configure vhosts locally for an apache
(Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3 according to phpinfo()).

Its set up via XAMPP (xampp-win32-5.6.3-0).
Operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium SP1.

So i already read some articles about setting up vhosts (also some in this forum). 
My host file looks as follows:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1   test.local
```

My C:\xampp56\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf contains the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias test.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp56/htdocs/test.local"
    DirectoryIndex app.php
</VirtualHost>
```

It is loaded in the C:\xampp56\apache\conf\httpd.conf file.

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The Module mod_log_config.so is also loaded in the httpd.conf

```
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
```

(After all editing in the config files i saved them and restarted apache.)

When I type test.local (or http://test.local) in FireFox it always says "test.local was not found". When i call up localhost however its working.

I havn't found any answers yet except to check if the vhost and the host file are set up correctly (which seems to be the case here to me).

Sorry for the long post and I am sorry in case it's just some stupid mistake i made here.

Thx for any help!

EDIT:

Here is also the output from the httpd -S command:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   test.local (C:/xampp56/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
*:443                  www.example.com (C:/xampp56/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:80)
ServerRoot: "C:/xampp56/apache"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/xampp56/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/xampp56/apache/logs/error.log"
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="C:/xampp56/apache/logs/" mechanism=default
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
PidFile: "C:/xampp56/apache/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

Comment: Looks like Firefox can't resolve `test.local` hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It was Avira blocking access to my host file .. disabled that option in avira and vhosts work fine now.

Beside that i needed admin rights which were not set for the account i was working with ..